# moving Qt directory

Tags: qt, macos, qt4

I'm working on a Qt4.7.3 project on mac osX (with xCode). I would like to move my Qt directory (installed with Qt installer). The problem is that some Qt executable files have hardcoded paths. I've already recompiled Qmake specifying the new Qt directory. So the project now compile and link perfectly, but at run time it cannot find the qt libraries (it still look into my old Qt directory). Is there other harcoded path somewhere, other configuration files to edit?

By the way, the reason why I want to move my Qt directory is to allow to share qt files via revision control tool.

Comment: have you tried grepping through the code to see if there are any hardcoded paths ?

Comment: I'm not sure what the OS X equivalent of linux's LD_PATH is, but I'd look into that as well.

Answer (score 2):

The pre-built installer actually puts all the framework files into the system location (/Library/Framworks/) and you will have a hard time moving those.

Your best bet is to build it from source and specify a different install location. [`./configure -help`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/install-mac.html) will show you how. (Use the `-prefix` option)

Comment: The last version of the installer does not install anything in system directories. Everything is placed in one directory. And anyway I would like to avoid Qt recompilation. Several developers must work with the same Qt files.

Answer (score 0):

Hard links could be a way to go in this kind of situation I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Create qt.conf file in the same folder as your **qmake.exe** file.

```
[Paths]
Prefix = E:/Qt/4.8.3
```

Follow this link for detail description.

http://richardt.name/blog/moving-a-qt-installation-directory/